# Redirect multiple domains to multiple domains

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multiple-domains

I did a website in wordpress and put it on the server. Currently I have 3 domains point to the same server, they are

```
domain.com.au
domain.co.nz
domain.co.uk
```

Even thought there is only one website, the content will actually be different according to which domain a user is accessing this website from.

I want to keep all the page authority and link juice, all the seo things, force www to be non www, and let google know that these three domains are three different website. My current htaccess file is like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: If you want all three website, then you should use canonical tag other two domain of you main site's. Google consider as one domain not three

Comment: But if i only use canonical tag, the ip address section would not make any sense(line 4-5) on the file

Comment: Add canonical in index.php not htaccess

Comment: Given that I have got canonical tags in my html, how could i for non www for all three domains? @Irfan

Comment: Try this:   `rewritecond %{http_host} ^www\.yourdomainhere\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomainhere.com/$1 [r=301,nc]`